# How to download video via viddl-rb?

Tags: ruby, youtube

I want to download video files from `youtube.com`, according links from my database.

I found `gem viddl-rb`, but I see only console way to download in documentation - `viddl-rb youtube.com/watch/myvideoid`

How to download video, using `require viddl-rb` in console?

Comment: According to YouTubes's TOS : Article 5B :
Content is provided to you AS IS. You may access Content for your information and personal use solely as intended through the provided functionality of the Service and as permitted under these Terms of Service. You shall not download any Content unless you see a ?download? or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content.

Comment: As far as I know Stackoverflow function's allows us to find answers to questions in programming in the first place. And I formulated the question accurately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please be warned that it may be against Youtube's ToS to download videos from Youtube; but anyways, following code might help you do it:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'viddl-rb'

YouTubeLinks = %w[
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8wLQ3NCBgg
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4
]

youtube_hashes = YouTubeLinks.map do |link|
  ViddlRb.get_urls_names(link).first
end

youtube_hashes.each do |yt|
  puts "Downloading: #{yt[:name]}"

  File.open(yt[:name], 'wb') do |video_file|
    open(yt[:url]) { |video| video_file.write video.read }
  end
end
```